# Setting / getting column number for reentrant Flex scanner

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lexer

I'm trying to set the column number so that I can retrieve it when the scanner fails.

I've read about the technique of using `YY_USER_ACTION` to increment a variable at [1], so I thought I could do the same for my reentrant scanner, but instead use the `yyget_column` / `yyset_column` macros that take a scanner as argument.

My attempt is this (not including my Lemon grammer/parser, since this is purely a Flex issue):

```
%{
    #include "BooleanParser.h"

    #define YY_USER_ACTION yyset_column(yyget_column(yyscanner) + yyget_leng(yyscanner), yyscanner);
%}

%option outfile="BooleanScanner.cpp" header-file="BooleanScanner.h"
%option reentrant
%option noyywrap
%option yylineno

%x DOUBLE_QUOTED

%%

[ \t]   {}

\n      { return NL; }
"||"    { return OR; }
"&&"    { return AND; }
"<"     { return LT; }
">"     { return GT; }
"="     { return EQ; }
"!="    { return NEQ; }
"("     { return LPAREN; }
")"     { return RPAREN; }
"true"  { return TRUE; }
"false" { return FALSE; }


[0-9]+            { return INT; }
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+    { return FLOAT; }
[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9]*    { return ID; }

["]                     { BEGIN(DOUBLE_QUOTED); }
<DOUBLE_QUOTED>[^"]+    {}
<DOUBLE_QUOTED>["]      { BEGIN(INITIAL); return STRING; }
<DOUBLE_QUOTED><<EOF>>  { return -2; }

. { return -1; }

%%
```

When this Lexer fails on this example input (mismatched '"', so my lexer will return -2)

```
foo = 1 && bar = 1.2 || b = "foo
```

then `yyget_column(myScanner)` will return 4, when I would expect something like 35 (the end of input). It seems it's not accumulating the way I thought it would.

So my question: With a reentrant scanner, what is the correct way to set the current column number, so that I can retrieve it when scanning fails?

Many thanks in advance (it's my first time using a lexer/parser generator).

**Update:** I've gotten a bit closer. I added a `printf` to the `YY_USER_ACTION` to debug the accumulation, like so:

```
#define YY_USER_ACTION \
    printf("yyget_column(yyscanner): %i, yyget_leng(yyscanner): %i\n", yyget_column(yyscanner), yyget_leng(yyscanner)); \
    yyset_column(yyget_column(yyscanner) + yyget_leng(yyscanner), yyscanner);
```

And the output with the input mentioned above is:

```
yyget_column(yyscanner): 0, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 3
yyget_column(yyscanner): 3, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 1
yyget_column(yyscanner): 4, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 1
yyget_column(yyscanner): 5, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 1
yyget_column(yyscanner): 6, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 1
yyget_column(yyscanner): 7, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 1
yyget_column(yyscanner): 8, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 2
yyget_column(yyscanner): 10, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 1
yyget_column(yyscanner): 11, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 3
yyget_column(yyscanner): 14, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 1
yyget_column(yyscanner): 15, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 1
yyget_column(yyscanner): 16, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 1
yyget_column(yyscanner): 17, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 3
yyget_column(yyscanner): 20, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 1
yyget_column(yyscanner): 21, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 2
yyget_column(yyscanner): 23, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 1
yyget_column(yyscanner): 24, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 1
yyget_column(yyscanner): 25, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 1
yyget_column(yyscanner): 26, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 1
yyget_column(yyscanner): 27, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 1
yyget_column(yyscanner): 28, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 1
yyget_column(yyscanner): 0, yyget_leng(yyscanner): 4
```

So it accumulates fine, but then in the end, it seems Flex resets it to 0 :( Any idea how I can prevent / work around this? Getting the column number is especially interesting after a failure.

[1] http://oreilly.com/linux/excerpts/9780596155971/error-reporting-recovery.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and answer myself: The "problem" is that since what happened on my test input was that the scanner unexpectedly reached the end of input inside a quoted string (which my rule with `<<EOF>>` matched like it should), and naturally Flex reset the scanner at this point, including the accumulated column number.

I realized now that this is a special case, and the column number isn't really meaningful at this point. It works fine for my other error condition (unrecognized character, where I return -1).

So, I'm happy now :)

Comment: I know it's old but afaik you're allowed to accept your own answer.